# Can there be more than one super weapon?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

In Tomb Raider multiplayer, there are two super weapons: competition bow and mini-gun. These spawn somewhere in a map and can be picked up, occupying a fourth weapon slot. If one person has picked up a super weapon, can any more spawn? How many super weapons can there be at one time?

Related question: It seems that one may pick up a super weapon that someone else dropped upon death. How long does it last on the ground dropped (and if there can only be one instance, how long before the next one of the same type spawns)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No.

> Whenever you kill someone with a superweapon, they'll drop it on the ground.
>   This is your time to pick it up! or make it time out. After exactly 30 seconds on the ground, they will disappear. 60 seconds later, they will respawn on one of the 3 locations.
>
> The choice to pick up the current superweapon or let it time out, it entirely up to you.
>
> ...
>
> 3 Tips n tricks
>   Don't forget these easy tips!
>
> - Only one superweapon can be in existence.
> - It takes exactly 30 seconds for a dropped superweapon to despawn
> - It takes a random amount of time (10-60 seconds, but usually 60) for a despawned weapon to respawn.

From the "[TR Multiplayer - Superweapons](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=133220679)" guide by [Xeno](http://steamcommunity.com/id/Xeforine/myworkshopfiles/?section=guides&appid=203160).